# @RequestBody not binding complex object

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to pass `json` object form `javascript` to Spring controller using `jquery ajax`. But if `json` object is complex it is not binding.

**Javascript:**

```
    var inputParam={};
    inputParam.name="xxx";
    inputParam.address.city="chicago";
    inputParam.address.zip="123456";

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url:"/myurl",
            type:"POST",
            dataType: "html",
            contentType :'application/json',
            data:JSON.stringify(inputparam),
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {


            }
        });

//Handle a successful call to data service
    jqxhr.done(function(  data, textStatus, jqxhr,response ) {
        // my successful code handle

    });

    //Handle an unsuccessful call to data service
    jqxhr.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {    

        //my error handling code

    });
```

**Controller:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String getMyPage(  @RequestBody InputParams inputParam,HttpServletRequest request, Model model ) throws Exception{
        //my code
  }
```

**POJO:**

```
class InputParams {
   private String name;
   private Address address;
  //getter setter
}

class Address{
  private String city;
  private String zip;
  //getter setter
}
```

The problem i am having is address is not binding on controller.

Any idea what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please provide correct type of parameter "name" in InputParams class.

Comment: Your JS code throws. Your Java code doesn't compile. Post real code.

Comment: I can't put all my controller code. And that is not necessary as well. My problem is inputParam passed from ajax is not binding on controller side.

Comment: If that is your real code, there is no way that your AJAX request can even be sent. Post real code.

Comment: Do you get an error or an exception thrown when the data is posted to your backend or just `null`?

Comment: @JBNizet i posted my real code.

Comment: @rieckpil i am getting null only for address object, name is mapped fine.

Comment: Your JS code still can't possibly send any request, since you're still trying to access inputParam.address.city and you've never defined inputParam.address. So either that's your real code, and something else is sending the request, or that's not your real code. Post your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your `inputParam` this way and this should fix your problem

```
var inputParam={
         name : "xxx",
         address: {
             city :"chicago",
             zip  :"123456"
                 }
           };
```